# vue.js: highlight in HTML a new object in javascript array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using a table which renders a collection of items.
Whenever I add a new item to the collection, I would like to highlight the new item in the table for the user for 1 second.
How do I access the new object from a .vue file and change its background color for 1 second?

This is my code for adding the new object:

```
var indicator = this.tableIndicators.find(x => x.id === indicatorId)
var indicatorIndex = this.tableIndicators.findIndex(x => x.id == indicatorId);
this.tableIndicators.splice(indicatorIndex, 1); //remove indicator from indicators collection
this.tableData.unshift(indicator); // add indicator to table-data
```

Comment: Hi, actually the best way to do it is CSS Animation, which will allow your newly added items to have a specific style for a certain duration. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#ad

Comment: @Stepehn, you rock!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Stepehn's link, this solved my question 'List Entering/Leaving Transitions':
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Entering-Leaving-Transitions